# R: Tidy row for each comparison pair

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to gather the rows for each pair of comparison. In other words, go from:

```
x=data.frame(id="Study1",
       t1=1,
       t2=2,
       t3=3,
       y2=0.1,
       y3=0.2,
       se2=0.5,
       se3=0.7)
```

to:

```
y=data.frame(id=c("Study1", "Study1"),
         t1=c(1,1),
         t2=c(2,3),
         y2=c(0.1,0.2),
         se2=c(0.5,0.7))
```

Comment: How are you supposed to know that `t1` will be doubled and doesn't have a pair column?

Comment: @CalumYou t1 is doubled because it has two comparisons: t1 vs t2, and t1 vs t3.

Comment: Ok, but from the data, how do you expect to know that? Or are you ok with a hard-coded solution for these specific column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape`

```
n=length(grep("y",names(x)))
reshape(x,t(matrix(3:ncol(x),n)),idvar="id",dir="long")  
             id t1 time t2  y2 se2
Study1.1 Study1  1    1  2 0.1 0.5
Study1.2 Study1  1    2  3 0.2 0.7
```

or you can use:

```
library(data.table)
cbind(melt(setDT(x),"id",data.frame(matrix(3:ncol(x),2)),t1=x$t1)
           id variable value1 value2 value3 t1
    1: Study1        1      2    0.1    0.5  1
    2: Study1        2      3    0.2    0.7  1   


reshape(x,data.frame(matrix(3:ncol(x),2)),idvar="id",dir="long")
          id t1 time t2  y2 se2
    1 Study1  1    1  2 0.1 0.5
    2 Study1  1    2  3 0.2 0.7
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't work for something like:x=data.frame(id="Study1",
             t1=1,
             t2=2,
             t3=3,
             t4=4,
             y2=0.1,
             y3=0.2,
             y4=0.3,
             se2=0.5,
             se3=0.7,
             se4=0.9)

Comment: @jackonator In that case what result do you expect?You are supposed to reshape the data. That's it.  in that case you need to have a way to recognize the way to reshape

Comment: In that case I would expect: y=data.frame(id=c("Study1", "Study1", "Study1"),
             t1=c(1,1,1),
             t2=c(2,3,4),
             y2=c(0.1,0.2,0.3),
             se2=c(0.5,0.7,0.9))

Comment: in that case you will include `n=length(grep("y",names(x)));
 reshape(x,t(matrix(3:ncol(x),n)),idvar="id",dir="long")` where there is `2` in the above when using `reshape` replace with `n` and it will work out

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `grouped` measure variables of `data.table::melt` as:

```
library(data.table)


melt(setDT(x), id=1:2, measure=list(c("t2","t3"), c("y2","y3"), c("se2","se3")), 
                                  value.name=c("t2", "y2", "se2"))

#Or in short form
melt(setDT(x), id=1:2, measure=patterns("^t[2-3]", "^y", "^se"),
                       value.name=c("t2", "y2", "se2"))
#        id t1 variable t2  y2 se2
# 1: Study1  1        1  2 0.1 0.5
# 2: Study1  1        2  3 0.2 0.7
```